# What is the appropriate cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to run the web ui on

> > 7474/webadmin/#

Suppose I want to find a node that has a property "title" with a value of "Home".
How do I find that node using a cypher query? (There should be only one node.)

Also, suppose I want to retrieve a relationship?
Let's say I have the following:
A -entitledTo-> B -entitledTo-> C

I have already tried the following:
start n=node(*) where  n.title='Home' return n;

start c=node(node_c_id) match a-[:entitledTo]->b-[:entitledTo]->c return  a,b,c;

However, I get this error message: The property 'title' does not exist on Node[0]

How do I resolve this issue?

Lastly, this is version 2.0.0-M03

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
start n=node(*) where has(n.title) and n.title='Home' return n
```

In general you should consider using indexes for this kind of operation, Neo4j's reference manual has lots of information about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`start n=node(*) where n.title! ='Home' return n;`

See [the section on missing properties in where clauses](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-where.html#where-default-false-if-property-is-missing)

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the Relationships, perhaps the Cypher PATH command could be usefull.